# Create attribute in a field based on the part of the name of a file in a folder with Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, path

I have a common path (F:\Comune) where there are folders with name that corresponds to the attribute of a field of the vector Zp.gpkg called "Numero".

The field "Numero" for every fid should have a different attribute that makes a valid path for different folder.

In the folders I have coded pdf name for different files. From every pdf the max and split function extracts a number that represents the most recent date (such as 20220701, in fact every pdf as name as lamba_20220701.pdf or similar).

The result such as 20220701 would be the attribute to the field "Ultimo_atto". My goal is to fill the field "Ultimo_atto" but something went wrong.

The original code was:

```
layer=QgsVectorLayer("P:\Zp.gpkg","","ogr")
print (layer.fields().names())

#adding new field
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
layer_provider=layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Ultimo_atto",QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
print (layer.fields().names())

#iteration that gives all the attribute of field = ["Numero"]
f=['Numero']
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print(f)

# d is the result that should be inserted in the field= ['Ultimo_atto']
import os
fish=os.listdir("F:\Comune\[%Numero%]")
x=max(fish, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0])
d=x[-12:-4]

# iteration that should allow to fill the field = ['Ultimo atto'] based on the result of the step before
with edit(layer): 
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(): 
        feature['Ultimo_atto'] = d 
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Here the code that @Ben W had developed (see answer).

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = QgsVectorLayer("P:\Zp.gpkg","Zp","ogr")
print (layer.fields().names())

#adding new field
layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Ultimo_atto",QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
print (layer.fields().names())

with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        fish = os.listdir(os.path.join('F:\Comune', feature['Numero']))
        x=max(fish, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0])
        d=x[-12:-4]
        feature['Ultimo_atto'] = d 
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

The field ['Numero'] was eventually filled BUT the result was not the most recent file in the folder defined by the directory os.path.join('F:\Comune', feature['Numero'])!!!
The attribute of the field 'Numero' was not the BIGGER number.

In the folder we have for example:
lamba_20090127.pdf
lamba_20091217.pdf

the field "Ultimo_atto" gave me "20090127" when it have to return the date of 20091217, which is the bigger value that should be obtained by "max".

It was a problem of type (string) that had to be transformed in type (int), but I did not know how to solve.

After long work I have found the solution

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = QgsVectorLayer("P:\Zp.gpkg","Zp","ogr")
print (layer.fields().names())


layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Ultimo_atto",QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
print (layer.fields().names())

with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        fish=os.listdir(os.path.join('F:\Comune', feature['Numero']) )
        res = list(map(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0], fish))
        int_list = [ int(y) for y in res ]
        z=max(int_list)
        feature["Ultimo_atto"] = z 
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Comment: @ Ben W I have changed the question and I added the old code just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several problems with your script which I would like to try to help you understand. Firstly, trying to apply the syntax which works in a feature action is the wrong approach. In the action script, I think that `[%Numero%]` is like a variable which is evaluated on a per-feature basis e.g. when the feature associated with the action is clicked on. It won't work the same way here. The way to access a feature's attribute is: `feature['Field_name']` or `feature.attribute('Field_name')` where feature is a `QgsFeature` object.

Now secondly, this block in your script:

```
#iteration that gives all the attribute of field = ["Numero"]
f=['Numero']
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print(f)
```

is definitely **not** retrieving all attributes in the field "Numero". Let's break it down. First, you are assigning the variable `f` to a list containg one item, the string 'Numero' (not the value in the field "Numero"). Then the `f` variable inside the for loop is not the same as the `f` variable outside the loop. It is actually holding each object returned by the `getFeatures()` iterator (`QgsFeature`) objects. So the result of those lines is actually:

```
<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7f5844d49b80>
<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7f5844d49af0>
<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7f5844d49b80>
```

To see the attribute values printed out, you would do:

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print(f['Numero'])
```

However, it seems like you are trying to define values in one iteration, then access and use them in another iteration, which is not how loops work. To do that you would need to store the values from the first loop into an iterable data type like a list or dictionary, then reference those items in the second loop, using an index. That is unnecessary here. Just define the `d` variable for each feature and update the `'Ultimo_atto'` field in the same loop.

As for building the paths to your folders, the best practice when dynamically constructing paths from different strings is to use `os.path.join()`.

Try the script below:

```py
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = QgsVectorLayer("P:\Zp.gpkg","Zp","ogr")
print (layer.fields().names())

#adding new field
layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Ultimo_atto",QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
print (layer.fields().names())

with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        fish = os.listdir(os.path.join('F:\Comune', feature['Numero']))
        x=max(fish, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0])
        d=x[-12:-4]
        feature['Ultimo_atto'] = d 
        layer.updateFeature(feature)

# If running script from Python Console, optionally add layer to project
#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

I tested this in my own system (with my own paths of course). I made 3 folders, each with a couple of PDF files, named like yours.

[image]

Folder 1:
[image]

Folder 2:
[image]

Folder 3:
[image]

In a geopackage layer, I have a field called 'Numero' which contains the folder name for each feature.

[image]

After running the script, you can see that the new field 'Ultimo_atto' has been added and populated with the date part of the most recent PDF file name in the relevant folder:

[image]

Comment: Your solution was fine but it prevented to obtain a reliable field "ultimo_atto", because of the use of a string to max function. The "Ultimo_atto" value were not the biggest value and so did not represent the most recent file